# fab fa-linkedin is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

According to new update `fa fa-linkedin-square` updated to `fab fa-linkedin` but when I use it then it is visible on hover only.

```html
<i className="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
<i className="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>
<i className="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-2x"></i>
```

last two lines are working as expected but the first line is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-font-awesome-pro-cdn-web-fonts-css-forked-h42rm?file=/index.html
I'm able to display it without hover. One probable cause for your problem might be color similarity between icon and background.Try changing icon color to a different color, it might solve your problem.